# PlaidLink is closed right away after the loading circle appears in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, plaid

I'm trying to open link using React Native Expo and I did the native config for Expo. Now whenever I try to open link_token using PlaidLink, the popup/page is closed right away after the loading circle appears. The popup/page is opened only when the `link_token` expired.

The `link_token` creation

```
{
   "user":{
      "client_user_id":"OMITTED",
      "legal_name":"OMITTED"
   },
   "client_name":"My application",
   "products":[
      "identity"
   ],
   "country_codes":[
      "US"
   ],
   "language":"en",
   "required_if_supported_products" : ['liabilities'],
   "android_package_name":"com.mycompany.myapp"
}
```

`PlaidLink` component

```
<PlaidLink
   tokenConfig={{
     token: "link-sandbox-",
     logLevel: LinkLogLevel.ERROR,
     noLoadingState: false
   }}
   onSuccess={(success) => { console.log(success, 'success') }}
   onExit={(linkExit) => { console.log(linkExit, 'exits') }}
>
    <Text>Add Account</Text>
 </PlaidLink>
```

PlaidLink closes with this result in onExit event : `{"metadata": {}}`

I need to see the list of banks to be proceeded

Comment: I hope you find a solution, but note that Plaid doesn't support Expo, so this may be expected behavior.

Comment: Yes the problem is resolved by downgrading the version. They are working on the current issue of the latest version. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug when using the Plaid React Native SDK and Android 13/14 that is currently being worked on by the Plaid team. More details are here: https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk/issues/620

Comment: Thank you! I've already engaged with this issue on GitHub.